# Associocommutativity

Tags: group-theory, arithmetic, abelian-groups, tetration, associativity

One thing I've noticed is that addition and multiplication both form commutative groups over the reals, but subtraction, division, and exponentiation are neither associative nor commutative. Ignoring issues with closure for division and possibly exponentiation, all 5 have the property that $(a \star b) \star c = (a \star c) \star b$ (that I call "right associocommutativity" because the swapped operands are on the right). Both left and right associocommutativity are implied by the combination of associativity and commutativity. However, tetration ($\uparrow\uparrow$, repeated exponentiation) has neither left nor right associocommutativity.

Now, my questions: Is there a better name for this? What other operations that aren't both associative and commutative have this property? Why doesn't this work for tetration? Is there a similar property that all of these operations have?

Comment: @Peter I accidentally made a typo. I never meant to say that either is associative or commutative. However, exponentiation has "right associocommutativity".

Comment: $a*b=a$ is not commutative, but has the property.

Comment: What do you mean with "right associative" ? The convention is that power towers are calculated from right, not left. But I would not call this "right associative".

Comment: @Peter Typos... Also, wouldn't that mean that it *is* "right associative"?

Comment: $a*b=a+2b$ is neither commutative nor associative, but has the property.

Comment: What is there to clarify, Peter? I'm defining the binary operation $*$ by for all $a$ and for all $b$, $a*b=a$.

Comment: OK, and this operation has the property mentioned in the question, OK, I got it.

Comment: @SolomonUcko Maybe, it is in fact called "right associative", but associative should mean that we can set paranthesis in another way (or completely omit them). Hence, such a terminology is at least unlucky.

Comment: @Peter Anyways, it was a typo, which I then corrected.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeftIdeal.html  right and left handedness is possible peter. Also if parenthesized the exponents in a power tower can have any order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that, if $G$ is an abelian group acting on the right on a set $X$ (say we denote the action by $\cdot$), then we can get another right action $*$ of $G$ on $X$ by $x*g=x\cdot g^{-1}$.

Since addition and multiplication can be seen as abelian groups acting on themselves, this allows us to also view subtraction and division in this way.

Now, note that any right action $*$ of a commutative semigroup $(G,\cdot)$ on a set $X$ will have the property that you want: $(x*g)*h=x*(g\cdot h)=x*(h\cdot g)=(x*h)*g$.

This explains all your examples.

Comment: A more spelled-out version: $(x*g)*h = (x\cdot g^{-1})\cdot h^{-1} = x\cdot(g^{-1}\cdot h^{-1}) = x\cdot(g\cdot h)^{-1} = x*(g\cdot h) = x*(h\cdot g) = x\cdot(h\cdot g)^{-1} = x\cdot(h^{-1}\cdot g^{-1}) = (x\cdot h^{-1})\cdot g^{-1} = (x*g)*h$ (assuming $(x\cdot g)^{-1} = x^{-1}\cdot g^{-1}$, which I'm sure is (easily) provable). Also, how would this apply for exponentiation?

Comment: $(x^{-1}\cdot g^{-1})\cdot(x\cdot g) = x^{-1}\cdot x\cdot g^{-1}\cdot g = \mathrm{id} = (x\cdot g)^{-1}\cdot(x\cdot g)$. The $\cdot(x\cdot g)$s then cancel.

Comment: I'm still confused how this would apply to exponentiation. What would the relevant group be? Thanks.

Comment: First, in your proof above, you make it seem like you use abelian-ness to get $(g\cdot h)=(h\cdot g)$, but in fact, you already used it earlier when you wrote $(g^{-1}\cdot h^{-1})=(g\cdot h)^{-1}$.  In general, in a group, $(g\cdot h)^{-1}$ is equal to $(h^{-1}\cdot g^{-1})$, not $(g^{-1}\cdot h^{-1})$.

Comment: Oh, oops, thanks. I'll comment fixed versions in a moment. Feel free to add them to your answer if you want.

Comment: Second, note that in the second part, I said a commutative SEMIGROUP, not group.
Exponentation can be seen as the commutative semigroup $(\mathbb{Z},\cdot)$ acting on the right on $\mathbb{R}$, or some such.

Comment: Oops: $(x*g)*h = (x\cdot g^{-1})\cdot h^{-1} = x\cdot(g^{-1}\cdot h^{-1}) = x\cdot(h^{-1}\cdot g^{-1}) = (x\cdot h^{-1})\cdot g^{-1} = (x*h)*g$. As for your second comment, exponentiation is neither associative nor commutative, so I'm not quite sure how that would apply, and neither are roots or logarithms. However $(\mathbb{R}, \log_{\frac1a}(b))$ forms at least a commutative semigroup...

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of an action?

The integers with multiplication are a semigroup, and they act on $\mathbb{R}$ by exponentiation:
$(x^a)^b=x^{a\cdot b}$. (This is exactly the definition of what an action is.)

Comment: Note that there are two operations in the expression above: exponentiation (which is the action), and integer multiplication (which is the associative binary operation).

Comment: Oh, interesting, thanks. I'll take a look when I get a chance.

Answer (score 7):

The algebras satisfying $(a\cdot b)\cdot c=(a\cdot c)\cdot b$ for all $a,b,c \in A$ have been studied in geometry. For a special class, see our paper [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_34_lr_algebras.pdf). Denoting the right multiplication by an element $x$ by $R(x)$, we can rewrite the identity as
$$
[R(x),R(y)]=R(x)R(y)-R(y)R(x)=0.
$$
So the right multiplications all commute. There are several $K$-algebras which are neither commutative nor associative and they arise naturally in many areas of mathematics and physics.

Comment: This is a bit too complicated for me at the moment, but I'll accept this at some point if there aren't any better answers. Thanks for the pointers, though.